# spark-shell ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Inside of spark-shell I keep getting the following error message in between my comment submitting.  What are these possibly about?

scala> 16/04/12 12:49:14 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 2 on XXXXXXXX: remote Rpc client disassociated
16/04/12 12:49:14 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 5 on XXXXXXXX: remote Rpc client disassociated
16/04/12 12:49:16 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 4 on XXXXXXXX: remote Rpc client disassociated

Comment: This is too broad to answer but first thing I'd look into is the memory overhead properties given to yarn by Spark

Comment: I agree, and I will definitely check the memory overhead properties given by yarn log.

Answer (score 1):

If you have dynamic resource allocation configured, these errors will show up when unneeded resources are released to Yarn. ERROR level seems misleading to me, perhaps INFO would be more appropriate. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation

edit: This should be fixed in Spark 1.6 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4134

Comment: Thanks, I think this totally make sense.